# MAMP: Apache denying clients

Tags: apache, mamp

I am using `localtunnel.me` to tunnel between local machine and a remote HTTPS server, it's not working for me. in error log I am getting following:

```
[Sun Apr 17 13:12:37 2016] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
[Sun Apr 17 13:12:46 2016] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/products/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost/
[Sun Apr 17 13:29:37 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
[Sun Apr 17 13:29:37 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
[Sun Apr 17 13:29:51 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/products/.DS_Store, referer: https://gdntrdlhyv.localtunnel.me/
[Sun Apr 17 14:46:17 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
[Sun Apr 17 14:46:38 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/products/.DS_Store, referer: https://epvztmlgwo.localtunnel.me/
[Sun Apr 17 14:48:48 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
[Sun Apr 17 14:48:48 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
[Sun Apr 17 14:48:56 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/products/.DS_Store, referer: https://grosjejjos.localtunnel.me/
[Sun Apr 17 14:57:43 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
[Sun Apr 17 14:57:50 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/products/.DS_Store, referer: https://gpyzbdhwqk.localtunnel.me/
[Sun Apr 17 15:13:49 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
```

I am using Apache 2.2 version shipped with MAMP. I am not getting clue why is it and how it's finding `.DS_Store` files.

Comment: The first two entries clearly show that this has nothing to do with the tunneling setup. It is a local configuration issue, apparently. So you will have to post the relevant parts of your configuration...

Comment: @arkascha Can you please elaborate? What do you mean by relevant parts?

Comment: Well, those parts of the configuration that might be of interest here: the configuration of the virtual host (complete), general configuration of the http server, where access is concerned.